# Am I understanding For Loops correctly? What am I missing? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, compare

This is a little game I am making to try to practice JavaScript with, basically the player picks a four color code and the computer has ten turns to guess it. I set up two for loops, one that runs through the player's four color code and one that run's through the computer's code (whatever guess(es) it makes). Within the loops are checks, if the computer's guess matches what the player put I want that value to be saved if not then the computer randomly chooses a different color and we continue on in this fashion for 10 turns or until the computer player guesses the entire code. The problem I'm running into is that if the computer's guess matches the player's that information isn't being carried on into the next turn. So if the computer guesses the first color as being purple and the first color is purple then the next turn the first guess should start with purple. Hopefully this makes sense. I suspect there is a much better way of doing this but I am a newbie. Here is a link to what I am doing.

http://codepen.io/terratunaz/pen/bNBoVY

```
var colorSelection; //the current selected color 
var clickCount = 0;
var playerCode = []; //holds player's code
var computerGuess = [];
var numColorValue = 0;
var computerSaveGuess = [];


//Fancy yet simple code to make the selectable colors respond to the user's actions   
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div.codeOption").mouseenter(function() {

        $(this).animate({
            opacity: "0.1"
        }, "slow");
    });

    $("div.codeOption").mouseleave(function() {

        $(this).animate({
            opacity: "1"
        }, "fast");
    });


    //Have the player choose a 4 color code amongst the 6 possible choices on screen and store that information
    $("div.codeOption").click(function() {

        if (clickCount < 4) {


            colorSelection = $(this).attr("id");
            playerCode[clickCount] = colorSelection;
            clickCount++

        }

        if (playerCode.length === 4) {

            $("div.codeOption, #inGameInstructions").css("display", "none");

            $("#hackCode").css("display", "block");

            $("#playersFinalCode").append("<p id='furtherInstructions'>This is the code you have selected. Press the [HackCode] button to continue, or use the button at the top right corner to go back to the main menu to start over from the beginning.</p>");


            for (i = 0; i < playerCode.length; i++) {


                if (playerCode[i] === "red") {
                    $("#playersFinalCode").append("<div class= 'playerCodeChoice'><div class='" + playerCode[i] + "'></div></div");

                } else if (playerCode[i] === "green") {
                    $("#playersFinalCode").append("<div class= 'playerCodeChoice'><div class='" + playerCode[i] + "'></div></div");

                } else if (playerCode[i] === "orange") {
                    $("#playersFinalCode").append("<div class= 'playerCodeChoice'><div class='" + playerCode[i] + "'></div></div");

                } else if (playerCode[i] === "yellow") {
                    $("#playersFinalCode").append("<div class= 'playerCodeChoice'><div class='" + playerCode[i] + "'></div></div");

                } else if (playerCode[i] === "blue") {
                    $("#playersFinalCode").append("<div class= 'playerCodeChoice'><div class='" + playerCode[i] + "'></div></div>");

                } else {
                    $("#playersFinalCode").append("<div class= 'playerCodeChoice'><div class='" + playerCode[i] + "'></div></div>");

                }


            }

        }

        //   


        //

    });




    function HackCode() {
        $("#hackCode").click(function() {

            $("#hackCode").css("display", "none");
            $(".playerCodeChoice, #furtherInstructions").css("display", "none");

            //Computer logic for guessing
            var computerTurn = 10;

            while (computerTurn > 0)

            {

                /*
 for(i=0;i<playerCode.length; i++){


         if(playerCode[i].length===5){
       //red

     }

        else if(playerCode[i].length===5){
       //green

     }

     else if(playerCode[i].length ===4){
         //blue
     }

    else
      { if(playerCode[i].length ===6 && playerCode[i][0] === "o" ){
        //orange
      }

       else if(playerCode[i].length ===6 && playerCode[i][0] === "p" ){
        //purple
      }
        else{//yellow
        }
      }

  computerGuess.push(playerCode[i]);




}*/


                for (c = 0; c != 4; c++) {

                    for (i = 0; i != 4; i++) {



                        //if(computerGuess[c] === playerCode[i])
                        //      


                        // numColorValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

                        if (computerGuess[c] === playerCode[i]) {
                            computerGuess[c] = playerCode[i];
                        } else {
                            numColorValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

                            if (numColorValue === 1) {
                                computerGuess[c] = ("red");

                            } else if (numColorValue === 2) {
                                computerGuess[c] = ("green");

                            } else if (numColorValue === 3) {
                                computerGuess[c] = ("orange");

                            } else if (numColorValue === 4) {
                                computerGuess[c] = ("yellow");

                            } else if (numColorValue === 5) {
                                computerGuess[c] = ("blue");

                            } else {
                                computerGuess[c] = ("purple");

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }


                $("#guessList").append("<li class='list'>" + computerGuess + "</li>");
                computerTurn--;


            }

        });

    }

    HackCode();


    //Clears whatever is on the screen and displays the main menu when the player clicks on the button to go there
    function hideToMainMenu() {
        $("#toMainMenu").click(function() {
            $(".codeOption, #toMainMenu, #inGameInstructions,#helpMenuInstructions, #hackCode,.playerCodeChoice, #furtherInstructions, .list").css("display", "none");

            $("#mainTitle, #playGame, #helpMenu").css("display", "block");
            playerCode.length = 0;
            computerGuess.length = 0;
            clickCount = 0;
        });
    }

    hideToMainMenu();

    //Clears whatever is on the screen and displays the actual beginning of the game when the player clicks on the button to go there
    function playGame() {
        $("#playGame").click(function() {

            $("#mainTitle, #playGame, #helpMenu, #helpMenuInstructions").css("display", "none");

            $("#toMainMenu").css({
                "margin-top": "-5px",
                "float": "right"
            });
            $(".codeOption, #toMainMenu, #inGameInstructions").css("display", "block");


        });
    }

    playGame();

    //Clears whatever is on the screen and displays the main menu when the player clicks on the button to go there
    function hideHelpMenu() {
        $("#helpMenu").click(function() {
            $("#mainTitle,#helpMenu, #inGameInstructions").css("display", "none");


            $("#toMainMenu").css({
                "margin-top": "5px",
                "float": "none"
            });
            $("#helpMenuInstructions, #toMainMenu").css("display", "block");

        });

    }

    hideHelpMenu();


});

/
```

Comment: Rather than have a `c != 4` in your loop constructor, you want to use a relational operator: =, <, >, <=, and >=, such as: `c < 4`. This way, you'll be able to include all instances from 0 -> 3 (0, 1, 2, 3) but not 4.

Comment: Where are you saving the computer's guess? Where is your computerGuess array declared? Some code seems to be missing.

Comment: My array is included at the top of my JS file. As for saving the computer's guesses I had created another array which is also declared at the top but haven't used it yet. I will edit my original post with the entire JS being used.

Comment: Thanks @Will I changed that. I originally had used a relational operator but then changed it when I couldn't figure out why my code was not behaving the way I wanted it too.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like your logic needs some improvements. This game should only need one for-loop as you only need to check whether first matches first, second matches second etc. Your problem currently is that it goes and checks if the computer's selection matches all the player's choices, and would only get carried over if it matched the last one.

Also you could save the right guesses in another boolean array. Then at the beginning of the for-loop check if it has already been guessed.

If you do want that the computer can guess first = red, and match it with player's second = red,you should add a break; statement inside the loop to stop it.

Comment: Forgive me but what exactly do you mean by a boolean array. An array with true/false inside? I'll experiment with use switch/case/break. Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly. Then you could have something like this (pseudocode):

Comment: Sorry, accidental enter press there. Here is the code

`guesses = [red, red, red, red];
 player = [green, yellow, red, blue];
 while turns left {
  rightGuesses = 0;
  for i = 0 to 3{
    if guesses[i] != player[i]{
      guesses[i] = new random color;
    }else{
      rightGuesses++;
  }
  if rightGuesses == 4{
    computer has won;
  }
 }`

Comment: I think I've got it to work but literally all I did was get rid of one of the for loops and had both computerGuess and playerCode use the exact same variable. In this case, "c". I'm actually not entirely sure why that worked and the nested for loop didn't because I was under the impression that it was essentially doing the exact same thing. lol 

I know you mentioned, "Your problem currently is that it goes and checks if the computer's selection matches all the player's choices, and would only get carried over if it matched the last one." but I'm not sure as to why that was happening.

Comment: In any case, thanks for the idea to use only one for loop.I actually didn't know that you could use the same variable to loop through multiple arrays like that.

http://codepen.io/terratunaz/pen/XJNzrX
If anyone is curious